# I receive multiple errors in SQL Server when trying to update a column in one table with a column for another

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update, subquery

I have two tables `dim_distributor` and `distributor_variant`.

There is a `distributorvariantname` column in `distributor_variant`, and a `distributorname` column in `dim_distributor` that should contain identical values between the two tables.

Both tables have a `distributorid` column that should contain identical values between the two tables.

There are some `distributorid` fields that are set to `0` in the `distributor_variant` table, and I want to update them to the same `distributorid` values in the `dim_distributor` table.

There is also a `distributorvariantid` column in `distributor_variant`, and I do not want to update the one that is set to `0`.

Below are the two queries I wrote to try to accomplish this.

The below query gives me a

> The multi-part identifier "dv.DistributorID" could not be bound.

I checked spelling, what am I missing here?

```
update distributor_variant
set dv.distributorID = dd.distributorID
from distributor_variant dv
join dim_distributor dd on dd.distributorname = dv.distributorvariantname
where dv.distributorID =0 and dv.distributorVariantID !=0
```

The below query gives me

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I tried in before the parentheses and received an incorrect syntax before the keyword 'in' error.

```
update distributor_variant 
set distributorID = (select dd.distributorID 
from dim_distributor dd, distributor_variant dv 
where dd.DistributorName = dv.distributorVariantName
and dv.distributorID =0 and dv.distributorVariantID !=0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Updating with a join requires some weird syntax. You have to say `update <alias>` (no actual table name) before you've actually stated what that alias is actually tied to. Try this instead:

```
update dv
 set dv.distributorID = dd.distributorID 
 from distributor_variant dv 
 join dim_distributor dd 
 on dd.distributorname = dv.distributorvariantname 
 where dv.distributorID =0 and dv.distributorVariantID !=0
```